# Javascript FileReader eats up all the memory when reads local images

Tags: javascript, html, filereader

I'm working on a concent to show the thumbnail of a large number of images from the local drive.

With HTML5 File API is seems quite possible, but whn I try to load a big number of images the memory usage of the browser goes over the roof and the collapses.

I think the problem is that the FileReader doesn't releases the memory after a file read.

Originally I had a new instance of FileReader and a simple loop to iterate through the images.

To solve this memory problem I replaced this to have one FileReader only, but it did not really help.

Here is the relevand code block:

```
<script>

var areader = new FileReader();
var counter=0;

function loadImage(file) {
    var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    areader.onload = function (event) {
        var img = new Image;

        img.onload = function () {
            canvas.width = img.width / 100;
            canvas.height = img.height / 100;
            var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
            ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, img.width / 100, img.height / 100);
            var browse = document.getElementById("uploadInput");
            if (browse.files.length > counter) {
                counter++;
                areader.result = null;//I don't think this makes any difference
                loadImage(browse.files[counter]);
            }
        };

        img.src = event.target.result;
    };
    areader.readAsDataURL(file);
    preview.appendChild(canvas);
}

function showImages() {
    loadImage(document.getElementById("uploadInput").files[0]);

}
```

If anybody come across this problem the I do something very stupid could you reply.

Thanks,

Tamas

Comment: How many images are we talking about here?

Comment: And how big are the images, too? Is this a problem in all browsers or just one?

Answer (score 10):

It's not the file reader but you are using the entire image's data in base64 as the `src` property of the image, which will actually take 133% of the image's size in memory.

You should use [Blob URLs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.URL.createObjectURL) instead:

```
var URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;

function loadImage( file ) {
    var canvas = document.createElement("canvas"),
        img = new Image();

    img.onload = function() {
        canvas.width = img.width / 100;
        canvas.height = img.height / 100;
        var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
        ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, img.width / 100, img.height / 100);
        URL.revokeObjectURL( img.src );
        img = null;

        var browse = document.getElementById("uploadInput");
            if (browse.files.length > counter) {
            counter++;
            loadImage(browse.files[counter]);
        }
    };
    img.src = URL.createObjectURL( file );

    preview.appendChild(canvas);
}
```

Comment: Even then, the browser has to keep the pixel information for all the images, no?

Comment: @Pointy well yea but you can throw the img away after `.drawImage`

Comment: Yes but it's got to keep the pixels available because at any time the code may ask for them back via the canvas API. At least, it seems so to me.

Comment: @Pointy in this example only the pixels in canvas are kept in memory, not the entire image and not to mention also the entire image duplicated as base64. `drawImage` doesn't make any references to the image, it copies the image's pixels to the canvas.

Comment: Ah well that's true; I guess that squeezing the image size down and drawing it really would free up all the "undrawn" pixels.

Comment: @Pointy Oh and also, javascript string characters take 2 bytes. So having the image binaries as 64 base encoded string in `.src` property would actually take 266% of the image's size as memory, yes? :p

Comment: The memory usage increases very drammaticly. It looks like each images (about 5M jpg) takes hundreds of Mbs of memories.